# I want a python script to change the background to black of a image of onion, how can it be done?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am trying to change the background colour of a onion image to black

I tried to write the code in python using opencv and pixellib but it won’t work and I am expecting some help to change this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Show the input image. We need to see what the background looks like.

Comment: Show your code attempt.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of an onion image to black using openCV and pixellib:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('onion.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(closing, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)

result = cv2.bitwise_not(opening)

cv2.imwrite('onion_black.jpg', result)
```